# How do I evaluate $\int_{0}^{[x]} (x-[x])dx $

Tags: real-analysis, integration

This is from a previous year university entrance exam.

The question is:

$\int_{0}^{[x]} (x-[x])dx $

The answer is somehow $[x]/2$.

What I thought of doing is that $x-[x] =\{x\}$. We know that $\{x\}$ is a periodic function of period 1.

Then $\int_{0}^{[x]} (x-[x])dx = [x] \int_{0}^1 xdx = [x]^2/2$

I am not really sure whether the question is correct or not. Any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: It's a bit confusing to have $x$ as the variable you integrate with respect to, also appearing in the upper limit of integration. Is it fair to say you are after $\int_0^{[x]}(t-[t])\,dt$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost exactly on the mark but you miscomputed. The last equation should be instead
$$
\int_0^{[x]}(t - [t])dt= [x] \int_0^1 \{t\}dt= [x] \int_0^1 tdt = \frac{[x]}{2}
$$
since on $(0, 1)$, $\{t\} =t$ and $\int_0^1tdt= \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: The variable of integration should not be in the limits of integration.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I thought that there is a printing mistake maybe. I just wanted to verify